# Windows 8,launch outlook from metro application

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps

I am trying to open out look from metro application (`vs2012`, windows store app).I used the following code:

```
 var mailto = new Uri("mailto:?rbethamcharla@hotmail.com");

 await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(mailto);
```

But I am always getting access denied error.Could some one please let know how to enable this acess of outlook from windows 8 store app programmatically.

Thanks & Regards
Ravi Kumar B

Comment: Working fine for me, though I used `mailto:rbethamcharla@hotmail.com` (without `?`)

Answer (score 1):

First of all Need to check the url the code should be

```
var mailto = new Uri("mailto:rbethamcharla@hotmail.com");
await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(mailto);
```

then it receives the email address. Secondly you can go through the link from msdn

[access outlook MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/9e71ba0c-d983-47ca-9cea-03a494c5801e/can-i-programmatically-access-outlook-from-a-metro-application)

Some steps might be helpful. Try making outlook your by default mail client.

Comment: Thanq all ,Now it is working after making my out mail as default mail client.

Comment: Please mark as an answer although I know that was not a big reply :P